# Smartphone headset jack to relay

Tags: relay, design

Looking to see if anyone has seen a relay triggered by a sound file played thru the phones headset. My idea is to connect an old smartphone to my home's WiFi and then connect it to my garage door opener switch. I would then write a small app that would send a sound file to the headset which in turn would trigger the on off switch.

Is it doable?

Update: Found a Bluetooth solution on the web that uses a N2222 transistor.

Thanks for the answers...

Comment: http://www.ti.com/product/lm567

Comment: Relays are triggered by current through the coil. If I understand correctly, you want to write an app that sends a digital audio file to your phone via WiFi, which then plays on an attached headset, a device with a microphone then recognizes the audio playback and trips a relay? Is this a digital Rube Goldberg machine? I'd say it's "doable" but the question is far too broad.

Comment: This is a common way to build IEDs :/

Comment: @JYelton He means the app plays a sound when it gets told to, not that it "sends" a sound file.

Comment: A link to your solution would be nice

Answer (score 2):

While you can't trigger a relay directly from the audio jack, you can trigger a transistor, which in turn triggers a relay, to do what you want. An external power supply would be needed for the relay.

[image]

[DSLR Remote is an Android app](http://bitshift.bplaced.net/en/dslr-remote/hardware/cable-s.htm) that is designed to work with DSLR remote release cable ports. One option is IR diodes, but transistors on the audio jack works with many phones (But not all).

A better option would be a bluetooth solution. Generally easier and well supported in many phones.

Answer (score 1):

Its doable, but I suspect that you'd get annoyed by the delays involved, not to mention mis-activations. Delay wise, the phone would have to link to your wi-fi when you got within range. That could be when you're halfway up the block, or maybe not until to get close to the door. If you have to wait there even 5 seconds, thats not so good right? I assume if you have to give it any attention (like arming it as you get closer to home), that would defeat the whole idea of it all happening automatically. Or worse, it might link to some neighbors "open" wifi router as your driving away, detect that, and still be in range of the opener. You'd never know you're leaving the garage door open as you drive up the street to leave the neighborhood.

I'll agree with the other poster that the question is a bit broad to answer beyond "yes or no" (sure its do-able). But for what its worth, its a bit of a rupe goldberg, and at first glance has a lot of opportunities for Mr Murphy to step in. With a little thought there might be an easier way to skin this cat. Especially with so many cheap and hackable wireless remote controls around.